# Users can't log in web service with LDAP authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, ldap

After the weekend (DST change) the users of a website I'm working on can no longer log in. The usrs keep getting the login popup to enter their credentials and in the `error_log` of ldap I can only see the following error

```
[Tue Mar 29 20:21:04.296466 2016] [auth_basic:error] [pid 5324] [client <<ip>>:58258] AH01617: user username: authentication failure for "/troubleshooting-webapp/": Password Mismatch
```

Although, when I verify the password using Apache Directory Studio, the password entered is correct.

An overview of (most) configuration files can be found below

**httpd.conf**

```
<Location "/troubleshooting-webapp">                                                                                      
  AuthType Basic                                                                                                          
  AuthBasicProvider ldap                                                                                                  
  AuthName "Web Site DEV: Login with User ID "                                                                    
  AuthLDAPURL "ldap://127.0.0.1:10389/ou=people,dc=company,dc=com?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)"                                
  AuthLDAPBindDN        "uid=admin,ou=system"                                                                             
  AuthLDAPBindPassword  "adminpwd"                                                                                         
  Require valid-user                                                                                                      
</Location>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.path}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.bindDN}" />
    <property name="password" value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.bindPwd}" />
</bean>
<bean id="contextSourceGroup"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.pathGroup}" />
    <property name="anonymousReadOnly" value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.anonymous}" />
    <property name="userDn" value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.bindDN}" />
    <property name="password" value="${prop:troubleshooting.ldap.server.bindPwd}" />
</bean>
```

**ApplicationContext.properties**

```
troubleshooting.ldap.server.path=ldap://ldap.server.url:10389/dc=company,dc=com
troubleshooting.ldap.server.pathGroup=ldap://ldap.server.url:10389/dc=company,dc=com
troubleshooting.ldap.server.anonymous=true
troubleshooting.ldap.server.bindDN=uid=admin,ou=system
troubleshooting.ldap.server.bindPwd=adminpwd
troubleshooting.ldap.server.searchBase=ou=people
troubleshooting.ldap.server.groupBase=ou=groups
```

I have been playing around with some parameters, and strangely enough, it doesn't matter to what DN is being bind to. It doesn't matter if it exists or not, the server will start and the error appears in the log.

The error is unique to this LDAP server. When I switch to the LDAP of the integration server, everything is working as expected.

Any ideas on where to start troubleshooting from this point on?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the cause of this issue, but reinstalling the ApacheDS server solved it.